# Bash script for multiple output files

Tags: bash, sed

I am attempting to use a bash script to create multiple output files from a file I have already created. As well as creating 10 output files I want to alter one piece of text in each of the files i'm creating from the original.

In the original document the starting lines read:

```
# For a single processor calculation
variable T equal 300 # Simulation temperature
variable salt equal 100.0 # Salt concentration [mM]

# Random number seed for Langevin integrator
variable random equal CPRAND
```

I want to change text that reads CPRAND to a random number in each file that I am creating.

The current bash script which I am using right now to try and do this is listed below:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
   cat me.sh | sed ’s/CPRAND/$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))/g‘ > “RunFile$(printf “%03d” “$i”).in”
done
```

I have not had any luck in getting it to work so far for multiple file creation. I appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use four spaces in front of your file contents and code instead of the `>` (which is meant for quoting). You can also highlight the block and hit the `{}` button to properly format it. It's difficult to understand how your file is structured with the way your question is currently formatted.

Comment: I tried to correct your formatting. Please verify that the input and script as shown are are correct. Are your quotes in the script really `“` instead of `"`? Also, what does `I have not had any luck` mean? Did you get errors? If so, show them.

Comment: And don't use `cat` here. `sed` can read directly from the source file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpret the content of the sed program, so the calculus you are doing gets processed by bash. Also, you can avoid the extra `cat` and the printf:

```
for i in {001..010}; do sed "s/CPRAND/$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))/" me.sh > RunFile${i}.in; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel 'sed 's/CPRAND/'$((1+RANDOM%1000))'/g' >RunFile{}.in' me.sh ::: {000..010}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using instructions GNU/Bash must interpret, you must use double quotes, instead of single quote, at end, the working instruction can be:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
   cat me.sh | sed "s/CPRAND/$((1 + RANDOM % 1000))/g" > "RunFile$(printf "%03d" "$i").in"
done
```